# @WebServlet annotation for JSP files

Tags: jsp, servlets

New to jsp and servlets in general. I've learned that I can skip url-mapping  in `web.xml` by applying a `@WebServlet` annotation to a servlet. Its also my understanding that what a jsp file is, is something that is compiled down to a servlet at execution time. Is it possible to also apply an `@Webservlet` annotation to a jsp file, such that the resultant servlet is already mapped, and I don't have to create url-mapping tags in web.xml for all my .jsp files?

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotation `@Webservlet` can be applied only to Servlet(java class).
If you want to get access to jsp, it's can be reach by two way:

1. Register jsp in **web.xml**
2. Create servlet with will redirect to jsp.

But add business logic to jsp is a bad practice. JSP responsible only for **view part** of `MVC pattern`.

> Model-View-Controller (MVC) is a pattern used in software engineering
>   to separate the application logic from the user interface. As the name
>   implies, the MVC pattern has three layers.

**Model Layer**

> This is the data layer which contains business logic of the system,
>   and also represents the state of the application

**The Controller Layer**

> Controller layer acts as an interface between View and Model. It
>   receives requests from the View layer and processes them, including
>   the necessary validations.

**The View Layer**

> This layer represents the output of the application, usually some form
>   of UI. The presentation layer is used to display the Model data
>   fetched by the Controller.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Of the two options, registering in web.xml or creating a servlet that redirects, do you know which is more common?

Comment: @anon20202 In my opinion, the second way is more convenient. Because many technologies and framework get rid of the xml base configuration and migrate to java base configuration. You could create RedictController and manage all yours redirect from one place